# Как проверить, есть ли у элемента с определенным id - определённый класс

Tags: javascript

Есть элемент с `id: one`.

Как проверить наличие `class: open-tab` у этого элемента?

```html
<div class="works-container">
 <div class="row-tab" id="tabs">
  <div class="tab-button open-tab" id="b_one"></div>
  <div class="tab-button" id="b_two"></div>
  <div class="tab-button" id="b_three"></div>
  <div class="tab-button" id="b_four"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="tabs open-tab" id="one"></div>
 <div class="tabs" id="two"></div>
 <div class="tabs" id="three"></div>
 <div class="tabs" id="four"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У `DOM` элементов есть свойство `classList`, которое возвращает псевдомассив. У него есть методы, и одним из них является `contains`. Он проверяет, есть ли у элемента класс.

**Element.classList**

**Описание**

Свойство **classList** возвращает псевдомассив [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList), содержащий все классы элемента.

> У **classList** есть примитивная альтернатива - свойство **className**, которое содержит значение атрибута **class** элемента.

**Методы**

**ClassList** является геттером. Возвращаемый им объект имеет несколько методов:

**add( String [,String] )**

Добавляет элементу указанные классы

**remove( String [,String] )**

Удаляет у элемента указанные классы

**item ( Number )**

Результат аналогичен вызову **сlassList[Number]**

**toggle ( String [, Boolean])**

Если класс у элемента отсутствует - добавляет, иначе - убирает. Когда вторым параметром передано false - удаляет указанный класс, а если true - добавляет.

Если вторым параметром передан undefined или переменная с typeof == 'undefined', поведение будет аналогичным передаче только первого параметра при вызове toggle.

**contains ( String )**

Проверяет, есть ли данный класс у элемента (вернет true или false)

> И, конечно же, у **ClassList** есть заветное свойство **length**, которое
>   возвращает количество классов у элемента.

**Источник**: [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("one").classList.contains("open-tab"));
```

```html
<div class="works-container">
  <div class="row-tab" id="tabs">
    <div class="tab-button open-tab" id="b_one"></div>
    <div class="tab-button" id="b_two"></div>
    <div class="tab-button" id="b_three"></div>
    <div class="tab-button" id="b_four"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs open-tab" id="one"></div>
  <div class="tabs" id="two"></div>
  <div class="tabs" id="three"></div>
  <div class="tabs" id="four"></div>
</div>
```